# Unable call external http URL using google cloud function

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to call external http URL using google cloud function. I have created topic in google pub/sub model and whenever there is new message received in topic, this function gets triggered. So this function should call that external http URL and request should be received at other side on http server. But request is not received on http server and in google cloud function logs i see only message as "Function execution took 60003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'". I have increased timeout to 300 seconds then also same error. When i run same code in eclipse it works fine and request received on http server but it doesn't execute via google cloud function. Not sure what went wrong? Can someone please help here to solve/debug?

My java code and pom.xml file as below:

```
public class Example implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName());

  @Override
  public void accept(PubSubMessage message, Context context) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    String data = message.data != null
      ? new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(message.data))
      : "Hello, World";
    logger.info(data);
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI("http://<<host>>:<<port>>")).build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(response.statusCode());
    System.out.println(response.body());

  }

  public static class PubSubMessage {
    String data;
    Map<String, String> attributes;
    String messageId;
    String publishTime;
  }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cloudfunctions</groupId>
  <artifactId>pubsub-function</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
      <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <!-- Required for Java 11 functions in the inline editor -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>.google/</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: how did you deploy your function? Did you use special parameters? (ingress, egress, VPC conntector...). Is a public URL? Is there IP filtering on the IP that you call?

Comment: Is your URL reachable from outside of your network?
Since you’ve said that it works in eclipse (locally) I would think that a firewall or something else is blocking Cloud Function to reach the server.